# How to ignore "/" in .htaccess re-write URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using .htaccess to hide the extensions of the my files which are in .php. Now suppose I've a file named "test.php" so If the user will enter "`site.com/test`" the file test.php will be opened. Now is there anyway in which even if the user writes "`site.com/test/"` (Slash / at the end of the URL ) is redirected or shows test.php? I just want my site to ignore "/" at the end.

Comment: Ignore my answer I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: @PanamaJack I've fixed it by `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302]'` Thanks to @DeDee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302]
RewriteRule ^test$ /test.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks DeDee, Is there anyway to do it with the every file? Not just test.php

Comment: Of course, the `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302]` checks for trailing slash and if found, removes it, then requests the file again (without slash) with `HTTP 302 Found`. Repeat only the last `RewriteRule` for every new file. E.g. `RewriteRule ^shop$ /shop.php [L]` or even `RewriteRule ^shop_bags$ /test.php?display=bags [L]`.

Comment: Thank you so much @DeDee Just adding `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302]` worked! Thanks again!